# How to split datetime strings column in a .csv file into seperate date and time column?

Tags: python, linux, csv

I have a column named date-time in the CSV file with values like:

`"Oct. 25, 2019   12:35:30"`.

I need to split the date-time column into two different columns named `date` and `time` separately.

No Idea how to proceed. Any lead would be a great help for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `pandas` package to read, process and analyze `csv` files efficiently.

Given a csv file like below:

```
date-time
"Oct. 25, 2019   12:35:30"
"Oct. 26, 2019   13:00:00"
```

Try the following to achieve your desired output:

```py
#after pip install pandas, import the module
import pandas as pd 

#Read your input csv file
df = pd.read_csv('your_file.csv')

#Convert all the string values of date-time column to datetime objects
df['date-time-obj'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date-time'])

#Create two new columns with date-only and time-only values
df['date-only'] = df['date-time-obj'].dt.date
df['time-only'] = df['date-time-obj'].dt.time

#Deleted temporarily created column
del df['date-time-obj']

#Save your final data to a new csv file
df.to_csv('result.csv', index=False)
```

Outputs:

```
                  date-time   date-only time-only
0  Oct. 25, 2019   12:35:30  2019-10-25  12:35:30
1  Oct. 26, 2019   13:00:00  2019-10-26  13:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

I would split the two using a regular expression during the parsing phase of the csv file. If you can provide your code I can give you a more specific solution.